# Stop the execution of a function from a package when its job is done

Tags: r, interrupt

I know how to stop a function that uses a loop using `stop()` or `break`. In my case I would like to use the `archive_extract()` function from the package `archive` to download individual files from a ZIP archive on the web. The archive has multiple directories with files, but the files one wants can be pointed specifically by adding the subdirectory name to the file names. So, for example, to download files `bcgarem7.sav` and `bcgchlz7.sav` in the folder `TIMSS2019_IDB_SPSS_G8/Data` in the remote ZIP archive, one can write:

```
archive_extract(archive = "https://www.iea.nl/sites/default/files/data-repository/TIMSS/TIMSS2019/TIMSS2019_IDB_SPSS_G8.zip",
    dir = "/mnt/docs/,
    files = c("TIMSS2019_IDB_SPSS_G8/Data/bcgarem7.sav",
              "TIMSS2019_IDB_SPSS_G8/Data/bcgchlz7.sav"))
```

I wrote a simple function to make the things more convenient:

```
library(archive)

download.data <- function(remote.zip, local.dir, file.names) {
               archive_extract(archive = remote.zip,
                               dir = local.dir,
                               files = file.names)
}
```

And then call it:

```
download.data(remote.zip = "https://www.iea.nl/sites/default/files/data-repository/TIMSS/TIMSS2019/TIMSS2019_IDB_SPSS_G8.zip",
          local.dir = "/mnt/docs/",
          file.names = c("TIMSS2019_IDB_SPSS_G8/Data/bcgarem7.sav", "TIMSS2019_IDB_SPSS_G8/Data/bcgchlz7.sav"))
```

This does the job, the two files are downloaded almost instantaneously, as they are below 200K. However, the function keeps working for another seven minutes which is the time needed to download the entire ZIP file (nearly 1GB). For some reason `archive_extract()` keeps working as if it downloads all files in the ZIP file after it has downloaded just these two files.

I would like to stop the execution after the desired files are downloaded. As there is no loop, checking the number of files in the download folder with `list.files()` and using `while()` and `break` to end the execution have no effect. Wrapping the call to `archive_extract()` in a condition with a call to `stop()` also has no effect.

Does anyone knows how to interrupt the function in this case after just the needed files are downoaded?

Comment: I'm confused as to how it could be selectively downloading just part of a compressed file  - are you sure those two files are actually downloaded first, with full contents, and not just created as placeholders?

Comment: Yes, the files are downloaded on the disk. I can open and view their content with SPSS or PSPP.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything you can do in R code. The function is implemented in C around here: https://github.com/r-lib/archive/blob/main/src/archive_extract.cpp#L165. The code loops through all the files in the archive checking if they match what you want. There's no early return once your files are found. You just seem to be lucky that your files are in the "front" of the archive. You'd have to file an issue with the package author if you want to change that behavior.

Comment: Thank you for the response @MrFlick. I was secretly hoping this won't be the case... I don't speak C or C++, otherwise I would have pulled a request for a change already. I did file an issue in May and it was acknowledged, but no changes were implemented yet. I was just impatient with this post. I understand the developers are rather busy, so it seems I'll have to wait.By the way, what do you mean by "You just seem to be lucky that your files are in the 'front' of the archive"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that today there is no good way to do this directly from within your script.

Within the [main loop of the C++ code of archive_extract](https://github.com/r-lib/archive/blob/main/src/archive_extract.cpp#L165) you can see it read through every single archive entry in the file, matching it against the list of desired files and extracting those that match. Once it's read all the files it continues doing the same thing, looking for a match in its now-empty list of filenames.

Now if [someone were to submit a pull request](https://github.com/r-lib/archive/pull/94) to that repo exiting the loop once the `num_extracted` value hit the count of filenames, you'd get what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you very much for the pull request. I am not able to evaluate what is done, as I don't speak C++. I hope it will be merged soon.

Comment: No worries. I verified that it worked in the handful of `archive_extract` tests within the test suite and confirmed from the command line that storing those two files from that archive took very little time compared to previously.

Comment: Sure. You can give my changes a shot yourself if you've got devtools installed: `require(devtools); install_github("allenluce/archive")`

Comment: I did install it. It works perfectly. The two files are downloaded in less than half a second. Thank you very much, you are the best.